# Code to replace a function to complete a Ticker

Tags: function, ticker

THIS IS WHAT I coded :

```
def statement(ticker,statement):
    if statement =='IS':
        temp='income-statement'
    elif statement =='BS':
        temp='balance-sheet-statement'
    else:
        temp='cash-flow-statement'
       
        df = tickers.temp(frequency='q') 
        return df

tickers=['AAPL','GOOG','TSLA']
```

I want the temp from the function to replace in the  df = tickers.temp(frequency='q') and finally giving me the correct financial statement when i replace the tickers with the stock code. If anyone has similar suitable code , Please do post it below

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want to achieve.
So i assume you have something like

```
tickers.income-statement()

tickers.balance-sheet-statement()
```

...
and you want to call the method according to the temp string in that function.
so

```
myfunc = getattr(tickers, temp)
```

should give you the desired function out of the string you achieved.